# Creating curved lines between two points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, points-to-line, curved

I am trying to create curved lines between two point in QGIS. There are a few posts that show how to create these lines (hyperlinks below). However, I am having trouble executing the code in QGIS.

This [article](https://jamesgeo.com/tag/quantum-gis/) says one could use the following code:

```
SELECT st_makeline(st_segmentize((SELECT geog FROM paths WHERE gid = 1), 50000)::GEOMETRY);
```

This [article](https://anitagraser.com/2011/08/20/visualizing-global-connections/) says one could use this code:

```
UPDATE experimental.airroutes
SET the_geom = 
(SELECT ST_Transform(ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeLine(
       ST_Transform(a.the_geom, 953027),
       ST_Transform(b.the_geom, 953027)
     ), 100000 ), 4326 ) 
 FROM experimental.airports a, experimental.airports b
 WHERE a.id = airroutes.source_id  
   AND b.id = airroutes.dest_id
);
```

It's unclear to where where to execute this code. I have tried several options that I outlined below which so far have not been successful. Here is what I did so far:

I think I may need to utilize the "Add PostGIS Table(s)" (the elephant icon) function. If so it's unclear to me what the Name, Service, Host, Database, Username and Passwords should be. This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165070/creating-new-postgis-connection-in-qgis) asked about this and the respondent suggested accessing pgAdmin, which I do not have and can't figure out how to get.

This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54000/qgis-postgis-is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-postgis-layer?rq=1) suggests executing the PostGis SQL code from the PostGIS Manager Plugin. However, this is not an available plugin from the Plugins library.

I have also tried to use DB Manager but when I click on the SQL Window icon I receive a message noting "No database selected or you are not connected to it."

Finally, I installed the Post GIS SQL Editor plugin but when I open the plugin I receive the following error "An error has occured while executing Python code:

```
TypeError: QComboBox.findText(QString, Qt.MatchFlags flags=Qt.MatchExactly|Qt.MatchCaseSensitive): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPyNullVariant'
```

Comment: You should start by installing PostgreSQL and [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/install/). Then you will be able to connect to it from QGIS. If you are on Windows the [EnterpriseDB Stack Builder](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) is the easiest way to install PostgreSQL, PostGIS and pgAdmin III at the same time.

Comment: @thibautg I'm working on a Mac and have installed PostgreSQL and PostGIS through the postgris.app. When I launch PostGIS my terminal opens outside of QGIS. It seems like I shouldn't have to do anything out of QGIS right? When I launch the PostGIS function in QGIS I am asked to enter a username and password which was was never previously prompted to create.

Comment: you must create a connection between QGIS and PostGIS. ([Similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133409/connect-to-postgres-localhost-in-qgis))

Comment: @thibautg It is unclear to me how to do this. I clicked the "Add PostGIS Layers" icon. I then selected "New." A screen comes up where I am asked to enter a username and password and several other credentials. I never created a username and password and when I leave these fields blank or put in random names I get an error message saying "could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting conections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PSQL.5432"?

Comment: there are many tutorials on the web on how to set up PostGIS like [this one](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01). For the Mac I recommend [KyngChaos binaries](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres) or Homebrew.